# Can't authenticate to GitHub from Git Extensions?

Tags: git, github, git-extensions

I'm just setting up Git Extensions in Visual Studio 2010 and can't really get it to work - I can't authenticate.

In Git Extensions, if I choose Plugins->GitHub I can add user, password, API token and choose SSH. Fine. Except that API tokens aren't available anymore as GitHub are moving to API v 3 now.

Anyone got news on this? I've seen a [very recent discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/reviewboard/browse_thread/thread/3c6e638ddd6a94a) but no clue.

Surely there must be more GitHub users than me using Git Extensions and having authentication issues?

Comment: Provide us more info API token isnt whats causing your problem its something about accessing the github API wich allows you to request repository data, user info, commit info, commit blobs... You really should give more detailed info

Comment: Git Extensions REQUIRES me to fill in my username, password and API token to access my GitHub repository. That's unfortunately all the info I can give you.
Maybe it's because Git Extensions isn't updated to meet the requirements of GitHub API v 3?

Comment: There is an RC to Git Extensions, released 4 hours ago. It solves the problem by, and I hope you're sitting, removing Github support. On the other hand, it's just an RC and not a release, also Github has Git repos in it, so it works.

Comment: there's an openissue in Github issue tracker for those curious. https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/issues/898

Comment: Well, I use it with SSH without problems. Configure your GitExtensions to use SSH connections with OpenSSH. Create a folder in your $HOME folder called .ssh. Go in there, use ssh-keygen and generate id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. Send the public key to github. Now use the SSH protocol for communication and that's it.

Comment: Can you try using it with HTTPS instead of SSH?

Answer (score 4):

Just for future reference: this has been fixed since v2.33