# GIT extensions does not connect to remote but git bash does

Tags: git, git-extensions

I actually connect to a remote repository and can do so using git bash
but not using [gitextensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).

git bash asks me for my password but GIT extensions does not. Does
anyone have an idea why this will be the case?

This is from GIT bash, which asks for my password whereas the GIT extensions does not ask for my password.

```
$ git pull http://vkaul@stash.int.linz.jumio.com/git/OCR/ocr.git
Password for 'http://vkaul@stash.int.linz.jumio.com':
```

Comment: would you mind pasting commad-line output here? it will be extremely helpful to see what works and what doesnt.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112781/11343 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10341662/11343 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open the Git Extensions main window
2. Go to Settings -> Settings
3. On the "Checklist", is "Git credential helper is installed" green or red?
4. If red, click the repair button.

This fixed it for me.  I'm using Git Extensions version 2.44

Comment: This must be new in git extensions. I don't recall seeing that checklist item before.

Comment: In newer versions, Its not in the main setting, no red or green espacially for the Git creds
Its in Settings -> SSH